# Store the checkbox state in a cookie session in JSP using Javascript on page refresh

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have check-boxes defined in my below function in my JSP page. Now the **checkboxValue** is the state of the check-boxes defined in the page.

On-click of check-boxes the **value is set to 'on'**, I want to save the **"on" state of the check-boxes** in a browser session or cookie session so that on page refresh the clicked checkboxstates should be maintained or  present in the check state only.

Can you please suggest me any approach to achieve this in my below code?

```
function() {
    var checkboxValue = this._checkbox.get('value');
    alert(checkboxValue);

    if (checkboxValue == 'on') {
        // do something
    } else {
        // dosomething else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#option_id').attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: get the id of the selected option then put it in session

Comment: Hi Restie,in mycase I have the (checkboxvalue ==on) this value i need to save in my session. Can you please suggest me some codes because I a kind of new to this cookie session concept to save checkbox values

Answer (score 0):

javascript

store:

sessionStorage.check=your checkboxvalue;

read:

sessionStorage.check;

Comment: I couldn't get the approach see here my check-box value = on so can you suggest me some sample code snippets for saving this state of the check-box state even on page refresh. I havent got exposure on sessions of cookies so would be great if you can provide some sample code..